# Search module configuration in DXA

Tags: dxa

When using DXA with the search module some configuration parameters are set in the component `\100 Master\Building Blocks\Settings\Search\Site Manager\Search Configuration`.

How are the `stagingIndexConfig` and `liveIndexConfig` parameters in this component published to the website? I expected to find them in the configuration page, but I cannot find the parameters in any page or component presentation.

I checked by means of [looking into Content Delivery web service](http://sharedbyjan.blogspot.nl/2014/12/a-peek-into-broker-database-with.html), checking [pages](http://localhost:82/odata.svc/PageContents) and [component presentations](http://localhost:82/odata.svc/ComponentPresentations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is configuration published in the standard way for DXA modules - in the form of a JSON file published as a binary variant when you publish the Publish Setting page. You will find it in the broker database with the URL `/system/config/search.json` - which will be also be serialized to disk under /BinaryData

Comment: I did find the BinaryVariant with path /system/config/core.json and /system/config/_all.json. For search I only found the /system/config/core.json. On the CM the "_System/Publish Settings" page only contains the Core configuration component, do I need to put the Search configuration component on that page? (using DXA JAVA)

Comment: Configuration for all active modules will be published - you don't need to add it onto any page. Check that the search configuration component is linked from the search module component, and that component (BB/Modules/Search/Admin/Search) has the active checkbox checked.

Comment: The system/config/search.json was in the broker, its just that the Content Delivery web service did not list it. With $top I could instuct the CD web service to show all results. localhost:82/odata.svc/BinaryVariants?$top=1000